# Algorithm to predict if trajectory of a line will come in contact with a rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, lua, line

I am unsure of what math to use here, as I am very inexperienced in the area of using math along with coding to solve problems such as this, so I was wondering if anyone here could either give me some pointers or give me somewhere to look at this specific problem. I have the x and y trajectory of the single point (or ball) and when it moves, it acts like a line, moving from one place in which is has to stop, then bouncing off of it (reflecting the trajectory), and going in that bounced trajectory. I just need the algorithm to give a true/false (boolean) to whether the current slope will come in contact with the rectangle. I have the 4 edge points  of the rectangle and the middle point of the rectangle if needed.

Comment: From a math perspective, you can calculate the slopes of the lines from some point on the path to each of the corners, and check to see if the slope of the path is outside of this range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back-and-forth in the comments, here is a function that may better suit OP's purpose. The `is_intersect()` function takes as input the position of the point on the trajectory, its direction, and a quadrilateral, and returns **true** if the point is on an intersecting trajectory, **false** otherwise.

`pos` is a table containing the position of the point, of the form:

```
pos = { x=x1, y=y1 }
```

`dir` is a number containing a positive angle in radians (0 <= θ < 2π) with respect to the positive x-axis, representing the direction of travel of the point.

`quad` is a table representing a quadrilateral, of the form:

```
quad = {{x=x1, y=y1}, {x=x2, y=y2}, {x=x3, y=y3}, {x=x4, y=y4}}
```

Note that it would be a simple matter, and perhaps desirable, to adapt the code to use integer-indexed tables instead, such as `pos = {x1, y1}` and `quad = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2},...}`.

This function works for quadrilaterals situated anywhere in the plane, and for trajectory points situated anywhere in the plane. It works by finding the positive angles with respect to the positive x-axis of a line through the trajectory point and each of the corners of the quadrilateral. The function returns **true** if the direction angle is in this range.

```
function is_intersect(pos, dir, quad)
   local theta_corner, theta_min, theta_max
   for i = 1, 4 do
      local x, y = quad[i].x, quad[i].y

      -- Find angle of line from pos to corner
      theta_corner = math.atan((y - pos.y) / (x - pos.x))
      -- Adjust angle to quadrant
      if x < pos.x then
         theta_corner = theta_corner + math.pi
      elseif y < pos.y then
         theta_corner = theta_corner + 2*math.pi
      end

      -- Keep max and min angles
      if (not theta_min) or theta_corner < theta_min then
         theta_min = theta_corner
      end
      if (not theta_max) or theta_corner > theta_max then
         theta_max = theta_corner
      end
   end
   -- Compare direction angle with max and min angles
   return theta_min <= dir and dir <= theta_max
end
```

Here is a sample interaction:

```
> test = {{x = 1, y = 1}, {x = 1, y = 2}, {x = 2, y = 2}, {x = 2, y = 1}}
> position = {x = 3, y = 3}
> pi = math.pi
> is_intersect(position, 5*pi/4, test)
true
> angle = math.atan(.5)
> -- checking corners
> is_intersect(position, pi + angle, test)
true
> is_intersect(position, 3*pi/2 - angle, test)
true
> -- checking slightly inside corners
> is_intersect(position, 1.01*(pi + angle), test)
true
> is_intersect(position, .99*(3*pi/2 - angle), test)
true
> -- checking slightly outside corners
> is_intersect(position, .99*(pi + angle), test)
false
> is_intersect(position, 1.01*(3*pi/2 - angle), test)
false
```

### How it Works

This section is for OP's benefit. Read no further if you do not want a Trigonometry refresher.

[image]

In this diagram, there are two points with directions represented by a green and a yellow arrow. The red lines connect the points with the corners of the rectangle. The `is_intersect()` function works by calculating the angles, measured from the positive x-axis, as in the diagram, to the lines connecting the point to each of the corners of the rectangle. You can see that there will be four such lines for each point, but only two are marked in the diagram. One of these is the largest such angle, and the other is the smallest. The direction of travel for the point is specified by an angle, also measured from the positive x-axis. If this angle is between the angles to the two red lines, then the point is on an intersecting trajectory with the rectangle. The green point is on an intersecting trajectory: the angle from the positive x-axis to the line of travel for the green point (what we might call its *velocity vector*) is between the other two angles for this point. But the yellow point is not on an intersecting trajectory: the angle from the positive x-axis to the line of travel for the yellow point is larger than both of the other two angles.

[image]

Now, in this diagram there are four triangles. Each of the triangles has an angle at the origin of the coordinate system. We define the *tangent* of this angle to be the ratio of the length of the side opposite the angle (the vertical leg of the triangle) to the length of the side adjacent to the angle (the horizontal leg). That is:

```
tan(A) = y/x
```

Furthermore, the angle *A* is the *arctangent* of *y/x*:

```
A = atan(y/x)
```

[image]

From this diagram, it can be seen that to find the direction angle of the line connecting the point on the trajectory to the corner of the rectangle, we can calculate the angle *A* from the triangle, and add 270°. We really add 3π/2 radians. For a variety of reasons which I will not go into now, radians are better. Once you get used to them, you will never use degrees for any sort of calculations ever again. If you ever study Calculus, you will *have* to use radians. But the practical issue at the moment is that Lua's trig functions take arguments in radians, and report angles in radians.

So, the angle *A* is *atan(x/y)*. How to find *x* and *y*? By subtracting the value of the x-coordinate for the point from the x-coordinate of the rectangle corner we can find *x*. Similarly, by subtracting the value of the y-coordinate of the point from the y-coordinate of the rectangle corner, we can find *y*.

We still need to know which quadrant the angle is in so that we know how much to add to *A*. The quadrants are traditionally labelled with the Roman numerals from Ⅰ to Ⅳ, starting from the upper right quadrant of the x-y axis. The angle in the diagram is in quadrant Ⅳ. We can tell which quadrant the angle is in by checking to see if the point is to the left or right of the corner of the rectangle, and above or below the corner of the rectangle.

With this information, the direction angles to each of the corners from the point can be found. The largest and smallest are kept and compared with the direction angle for the trajectory of the point to see if the trajectory will intersect the rectangle.

The above exposition is a pretty good description of what the code in the `is_intersect()` function is doing. There is a subtlety in that the subtraction to find the sides of the triangles gives negative side-lengths in some cases. This is a normal issue in trigonometric calculations; the code needs to know how the `atan()` function being used handles negative values. The code under the comment `-- Adjust angle to quadrant` takes this into account.

[image]

For the case of a coordinate system with the origin at the upper left, you simply need to measure angles in a clockwise fashion instead. This is analagous to flipping the original coordinate system upside down. By the way, the original coordinate system (with the origin at the lower-left) is the one usually found in Mathematics, and is called a *right-handed* coordinate system. The other system, with the origin at the upper-left, is called a *left-handed* coordinate system.

### Addendum

In an attempt to help OP understand these functions, I provided [this simple testing code](http://pastebin.com/S8qXVhwU). What follows is a further attempt to explicate these tests.

[image]

The above diagram shows in part the situation represented in the tests. There is a 1X1 rectangle located in quadrant I. Note that these are screen coordinates, with the origin at the upper left. All angles are measured in a clockwise direction from the positive x-axis.

In the tests you will find:

```
pos1 = { x = 0, y = 0 }
pos3 = { x = 3, y = 3 }
```

These are two positions from which we wish to test the functions. The first position is at the origin, the second is at the location (3, 3). The red lines in the diagram help us to see the direction angles from the test points to the corners of the rectangle.

First note that **A** = *atan(1 / 2)*, or **A** = *atan(.5)*. This angle will show up again, so I have defined the constants:

```
angle = math.atan(.5)
pi = math.pi
```

Next notice that the angle **B** is (π/2 - **A**) radians. Convince yourself that this is true by looking at the symmetry of the situation. There is no need to convert any of these angles to degrees, in fact *do not do this*! This will only cause problems; the usual trig functions expect arguments in radians, and return angles in radians.

Continuing, if you look closely you should be able to see that the angle **C** is (π + **A**) radians, and the angle **D** is (3π/2 - **A**) radians.

So we have, for example, these tests:

```
{ pass = true, args = { pos1, pi/4, rect } },
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, 5*pi/4, rect } },
```

The first of these tests the trajectory from position `pos1`, (0, 0), with a direction angle of π/4 radians. This should intersect the corner nearest `pos1`. The second tests the trajectory from position `pos3`, (3, 3), with a direction angle of 5π/4 radians. This should intersect the corner nearest `pos3`. So both tests should return `true`.

There are also tests like:

```
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, pi + angle, rect } },
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, 3*pi/2 - angle, rect } },
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, 1.1*(pi + angle), rect} },
{ pass = false, args = { pos3, 1.1*(3*pi/2 - angle), rect } },
{ pass = false, args = { pos3, .99*(pi + angle), rect } },
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, .99*(3*pi/2 - angle), rect } },
```

Now `pi + angle` and `3*pi/2 - angle` are the direction angles to the outside corners of the rectangle from `pos3`, as previously noted. So the first two tests should return `true`, since we expect trajectories directed at the corners to intersect the rectangle. The remaining tests make the direction angles larger or smaller. Looking back at the diagram, note that if the direction angle of the trajectory from `pos3` is made larger than **C**, there should be an intersection, but if it is made smaller than **C**, there should not be an intersection. Similarly, if the direction angle of the trajectory from `pos3` is made larger than **D**, there should be *no* intersection, while if it is is made smaller, there *should* be an intersection.

All of this is just to explain what is happening in the tests, so that you can understand them and write tests of your own. In practice, you only need to specify the quadrilateral with the `quad` table, a position with the `pos` table, and a direction with `dir`, which is a `number` in radians. You specified straight-line motion; curvilinear motion is more involved.

After all of this, I still strongly suggest, as I did earlier in the comments, that you consider using [@Gene's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42016044/6879826). To use this function you specify a direction vector instead of an angle, using a table: `dir = {x = x1, y = y1)`. This will save you many troubles, and as you mentioned earlier, you already have x- and y-components for the direction of the trajectory. Converting this information to an angle will require you to understand how to make the correct adjustments for the quadrant of the angle. Don't mess with this right now.

Here are the tests of position `pos3` for Gene's function:

```
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, {x=-1.01, y=-2}, rect} },
{ pass = false, args = { pos3, {x=-0.99, y=-2}, rect } },
{ pass = false, args = { pos3, {x=-2.01, y=-1}, rect } },
{ pass = true, args = { pos3, {x=-1.99, y=-1}, rect } },
```

Instead of worrying about angles, and referring back to the last diagram, note that arrows from `pos3` to the outside corners of the rectangle can be drawn by going 1 in the negative x-direction, and 2 in the negative y-direction, or by going 2 in the negative x-direction and 1 in the negative y-direction. So to test for slightly off-corner intersections, as before, the x-components of the trajectory direction vectors are modified. For example, from `pos3`, the trajectory `{-2, -1}` should intersect at the corner nearest the y-axis. So, the trajectory `{-2.01, -1}` should *not* intersect with this corner, and the trajectory `{-1.99, -1}` *should* intersect.

One caveat. Notice that there are four tests, and not six as before. Gene's function will report that there is no intersection from `pos3` with the trajectory vector `{-2, -1}`. This is not incorrect, but just a difference in the way his code handles corner cases. In fact, I should probably remove the tests that directly test at the corners of the rectangle for my function, and just test *near* the corners, which is what really matters. Both functions report the same results for all other cases. The tiniest bit away from a corner, and both functions report `false`; the tiniest bit inside the corners, and both functions report `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll be sure to reply again with my results! Also, is the slope intercept form used with the coordinates or the trajectory?

Comment: I'm unsure of what m_corner, m_min, and m_max is, same with x_min and x_max. Is intercept defined by default? Also, if the rectangle is constantly moving randomly, should I replace the x and y in quad with the defined x and y? What I meant by trajectory is ONLY the direction of the line, not the coordinates, where the coordinates are moving is the trajectory.

Comment: The pos and quad are required be added to the second algorithm right? Update: never mind I see that the example includes all the requirements, again, thank you very much! Also, is there anyway you could elaborate more on the exact processes going on with this so I could possibly recreate it for others?

Comment: I will elaborate on the second function, which is much better than the first, later when I have some time. It just takes a bit of trigonometry, and maybe some familiarity with vectors :)

Comment: Thank you, I have never taken trigonometry yet, but I definitely plan to.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but does it matter to the algorithm if the y coordinates are higher in value (0,9) when lower to the ground and lower in value (0,0) when higher to the ceiling? @David Bowling

Comment: No bother. If you are talking about a coordinate system with the origin in the upper left-hand corner, like a display window, then the only difference is that you need to measure the direction angle differently. Instead of measuring in a clockwise direction from the positive x-axis, you will have to measure in a counter-clockwise direction from the positive x-axis. That is, down from the top instead of up from the bottom. I will try to explain more when I get back to this answer later :)

Comment: @P.Pat-- Answer updated. I hope that this helps; after reading through this I would suggest making a drawing of a small rectangle (2-3 units per side) on a small coordinate system, and drawing some points around it at convenient locations. You can try calculating angles from this and checking against the function for different trajectory directions at each point. This might help cement things.

Comment: Hello again, I'm having trouble figuring out if I should just put a negative on the y since the 0,0 position is in the top left and leave the x positive, would that work with your algorithm?

Comment: If you look at the final diagram, where the axes cross is (0, 0). Note arrows on axes. These indicate that y grows in a positive sense downwards, and x grows in a positive sense to the right. Negative values would be above and to the left. If you are using this diagram, your direction angles are measured in a clockwise direction. (I just noticed that I wrote counter-clockwise here-- the diagram is correct... will fix). Once you decide on the coordinate system, you must be consistent. The point in the last diagram could be, e.g., (x = 6, y = 2) with direction angle of, say 3π/4 rad (135°).

Comment: The algorithm will work for points and rectangles with negative coordinates, i.e., to the left of the y-axis, or above the x-axis in the final diagram. So long as you are consistent and measure the angles in the right direction.

Comment: So if I put 22931 y and 44582 in the algorithm, it knows that 22931 is higher on the y axis than 44582? Also is this algorithm able to detect the Boolean answer before 16ms? Or is that dependent on the cpu?

Comment: Not sure I follow. `y=22931` would be lower than `y=44582` on the y-axis, but higher on the screen (with upper-left origin). You only need to worry about getting the right screen coordinates and the algorithm handles them. Don't know about timing. I would guess that is in the right ballpark, but I only ever time C functions; I don't really have a sense of Lua execution times. And yes, it would depend on your machine. For speed, [@Gene's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42016044/6879826) is certainly faster. If I really wanted efficiency, I would probably write this in C.

Comment: Hello again, a couple questions while i'm implementing this, does it matter if the coordinate plane the rectangle and point are in is infinite? Second, is theta just a representation of the angle or slope/trajectory of the line? I only have an xtrajectory and ytrajectory to work with; they act like slopes, having a specific value of points it goes up in one tick, example is [downangle](https://puu.sh/tOXgu/2ab5f4b3df.mp4) in which the slope is xtrajectory(-+)62672 ytrajectory(-+)19161, no angles (degrees). Would these values be input into theta? Is theta the rectangular plane (stage) data?

Comment: @P.Pat-- Well, not infinite because in Lua the `number` type is really a C `double`; limits are system-dependent, but on my system the largest `double` is a little less than 2e308. But the numbers you provided will be fine. The _math_ will work for any size of plane. Theta is an angle. If you only have x- and y-coordinates I would suggest using [@Gene's function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42016044/6879826), which is perfectly fine and takes the direction in the form `dir = { x=x_comp, y=y_comp }`. Draw a picture of the coordinate system, reference everything to this, and you'll be fine.

Comment: You may find it useful to [read about vectors](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html).

Comment: I should be able to find the degrees with arctan(rise/run) right? Then after that, find the radians from the degrees? Are the radians required? Once I find the radians do i have to situate them or add to them to make them part of the 4th quadrant? Would i simply add 300 degrees?

Comment: More tricky than that. If you are using angles, you must handle all quadrants since the direction can make any angle with the x-axis. You must use radians, but most trig functions, certainly Lua's `atan`, return angles in radians anyway. Since you already have direction as x- and y-coordinates I strongly suggest that you try @Gene's function. This will reduce the chance of errors. [Here is a Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/S8qXVhwU) to the functions and some simple unit tests that I wrote. You can run/modify the tests, and see how the functions are used. I included a few comments and notes

Comment: I'm confused what I should do with angle, should it always = arctan(.5) or should it = arctan(slope)? Since that gives me an angle?

Comment: Also, when doing `rad = math.atan(ytrajectory/xtrajectory)*pi/180
pi = math.pi
angle = math.atan(xtrajectory/ytrajectory)
dir = angle <= rad < 2*pi` it gives an error on dir about comparing a boolean with a number.

Comment: Update: fixed dir problem, now: `attempt to perform arithmetic on a table value (local 'y')` is given when doing `theta_corner = math.atan((y - pos.y) / (x - pos.x))`

Comment: @P.Pat-- I have added a new diagram and further explanations about the tests. I can't teach you about vectors or trigonometry in this format. I don't mean to discourage you, but I can do no more. Good luck with coding, and learn as much math as you can; it _will_ be useful if you continue to write code. Plus, mathematics is beautiful in its own right :)

Answer (score 1):

IMO `atan` is a bad idea. It's expensive, and the quadrant adjustment is way too hard.

You can simplify the accepted code by using `atan2` rather than `atan`, but that's still too expensive.

You don't really care about the angle. You care about the *signs* of the angles between the direction vector and the extreme vectors from current position to box corners.

For this, cross-products are cheaper, simpler, and better-suited. If you have two vectors a and b, then the quantity:

```
s = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x
```

is positive if the acute angle from a to b is positive (counter-clockwise) and vice versa.

You need only to verify that the acute angles formed by the direction vector and lines from the current point to each of the box corners include at least one positive and one negative result.

```
function is_intersect(pos, dir, quad)
  local n_pos, n_neg = 0, 0
  for i = 1, 4 do  
    local dx, dy = quad[i].x - pos.x, quad[i].y - pos.y
    local s = dir.x * dy - dir.y * dx
    if s > 0 then n_pos = n_pos + 1 end
    if s < 0 then n_neg = n_neg + 1 end
  end
  return n_pos > 0 and n_neg > 0
end
```

Sorry I'm not a Lua programmer. This is a best guess at Lua syntax using the already-accepted answer as a pattern.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and good points about expensive function calls. I sort of backed into my answer, as it seemed that OP was asking a slightly different question at the start. I started to think about changing to something like this when I needed to explain the quadrant adjustments (which I really glossed over). Although, I don't think that OP has familiarity with vectors and cross-products.

Comment: I indeed do not have that familiarity.

Comment: @Gene-- This code does run, so good guess :) Note that `dir` in your function is a vector represented by a table of the form `{x=x1, y=y1}` instead of the angle in my function. I had written some simple unit tests for my function, and I modified them to test your function. It passed, except it failed to detect glancing intersections at the corners of the rectangle. This is because of the tests `s > 0` and `s < 0`. The simplest fix may be to first compare `s < epsilon`, and if so return `true`. I used `epsilon = 1e-6` and all tests were passed. Also, there is no `atan2` in Lua, AFIK; in C, yes.

Comment: Actually, there is math.atan2 (x, y)

Comment: @P.Pat-- I stand corrected! I had looked through the math library functions in the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html), and didn't see it. But now I look again, and see that `atan2()` has been deprecated in 5.3, but it is still there.

Comment: @DavidBowling Whether to include degenerate intersections is a design decision. I chose to omit them.  As you say, it's easy to include corners and sides if you want them.

Comment: Agreed. Just thought it might be useful, especially for OP and others, to point this out in the comments :) Maybe talk of a "fix" was a poor choice of words.

Comment: @ad absurdum, I was off from work hence did not see the activities. Thank you for showing direction.

Comment: @Ollie, my post is not an answer rather a sub-question based on the accepted answer for my language of development. I needed help and had the idea that I am making some mistake.
The compelling reason to continue on same thread is the fact that this thread is quite small and keeping it here does not cause any distractions.

Comment: @Gene I do not have the x and y of 'dir' just an angular value then how do I use your solution, it would be great if you can suggest a way out.